# How can I dock forms that are stored in a DLL or from other apps

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-xe8, jedi

I want to build an app with plugins. Plugins will be DLL files (Delphi and Jedi Plugins framework).

Some plugins will have a Form with controls. I want those Forms inside DLLs to be able to dock with the main app's Form.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Not easy with the VCL, unless you use packages rather than DLLs.

Comment: Your DLL and your application must use VCL runtime packages so that a TForm in the DLL is a TForm in the application (By "is", I mean Delphi "IS" operator).

Comment: If not using runtime packages, you must play at Windows level to makes the DLL form parented in the mainform in the app. There is likely to have difficulties to keep consistent behavior (Tab and focus control).